# get div scroll bottom - 220 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an alert when the user scroll the div till quite the end of it.

So I tried

```
$('#rightinbox').scroll(function() {
if ($('#rightinbox').scrollTop() >= $('#rightinbox').height() - $('#rightinbox').height() - 220){
alert("it is quite near to the end of the div");
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tax5f1fq/

the problem is, the alert is showing every time. I want to show just when the scroll bar is near to the end of the div. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolltop is a positive value, and on the right side of your if expression you have a negative one.

```
x - x - 220 = -220
```

Comment: oh, yeah, the problem is `$('#rightinbox').height()` give me the div height without the scroll, I want to get the div height with the content/scroll to make it work!

Comment: You're wrong. Try subtracting a lot less than 220, perhaps up to 10. So that gives us: if $('#rightinbox').scrolltop() >= $('#rightinbox').height() - 10